# How to enable own menu item in SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui, menuitem

I have SwiftUI app with storyboard menu where I added my own item which is disabled when I run the app. I created following class to make it enabled and I call initMenu method from applicationDidFinishLaunching in AppDelegate but menu item still remains disabled, what else or additional I have to do to make it enabled?

```
class MenuActions: NSObject {

func initMenu() {
    let mainMenu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu
    mainMenu?.autoenablesItems = false
    mainMenu?.item(at: 1)?.submenu?.item(at: 0)?.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func new(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    print("fired")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside AppDelegate you can just add the IBaction

```
@IBAction func new(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    print("fired")
}
```

Then connect the Menu Item in the Storyboard file with that function and it is enabled by default.

**Edit:**

You can create your own Menu class which handles the MenuItems action like this:

```
class MenuItems : NSObject {
    @IBAction func new(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        print("fired")
    }
}
```

Then add an `Object` in the storyboard to the Application Scene and set your custom class to that object. Thereafter connect your IBactions

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there any way to put @IBAction somewhere else than in AppDelegate? Just for curiosity.

Comment: Yes you can create custom class aswell, add it to your storyboard and connect the IBactions aswell. Edited above

Comment: Sorry to bother again but what do you mean by "add an Object to Application Scene"? I can`t make Ctlr-drag connection to IBAction new if it`s not placed in AppDelegate.

Comment: No worries, you go to the Storyboard. Then at the top of Xcode you have a "+" button. Search for Object and add it to the top bar of the MenuBar.

Comment: Thank you a lot.